# Azure, Live Smooth Streaming

Tags: iis, streaming, azure

Does Windows Azure supports IIS Live Smooth Streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the nodes on which our apps. run doesn't support Live Smooth Streaming (also you need to have access to the IIS for live smooth streaming). Instead you can set up a Windows Server 2008 with IIS on a VM role, use Blobs for the content and CDNs for delivery. Also you can use some workers role for encoding. The MS Expression Encoder 4.0 has an API ready to be used for media enconding.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multimedia that you want streamed I would look into Azure CDN http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/cdn/ or Azure Blob Storage  and Silverlight as an adaptive smooth streamer http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/streamingazure for your IIS Live Smooth Streaming.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out Microsoft Nimbus Media Service - IIS Smooth Streaming Service in the cloud. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/media-services/

I am a PM in IIS team (Azure Media Service). We launched Nimbus a month before and currently it is in preview. You could apply through the link above to get early access.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick google search:

http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Azure+Smooth+Streaming

Answer (score 0):

Steve Marx, PM for windows Azure has two blog posts you may want to have a look at.

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/publishing-adaptive-streaming-video-from-expression-encoder-to-windows-azure-blobs

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/smooth-streaming-with-windows-azure-blobs-and-cdn

Both have been very helpful to me.

Steve  is @smarx on twitter. I'm sure he'll be able to help you.